# What does mean that two matrices are similar in terms of its minimal polynomial?

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

Let $p_T(x) = (x-3)^2(x-7)^4(x-1)^3$ and $p_H(x) = (x-3)^4(x-7)^3(x-1)^2$ two minimal polynomials of the operators $T$ and $H$?

What does mean to define if $T$ and $H$ are similar just looking at these two polynomials?

Comment: Usually "similar" is defined as "equivalent through a change of basis". It's an important theorem that similar matrices have identical minimal polynomials. You've provided two minimal polynomials with the same set of roots, but different multiplicities, so $T$ and $H$ cannot be similar. Are you asking how to prove this equivalence, or if there is a significance two operators having minimal polynomials with identical roots but different multiplicities?

Comment: @AlexMeiburg, I was jut asking for this result that you stated! Thank you so much! It is clear now. They cannot be similar because they have different's algebraic multiplicities, right?

Comment: Correct. The minimal polynomials being the same is necessary but not sufficient for them to be similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar matrices have the same minimal polynomial and the same characteristic polynomial, but the converse is not true: two non-similar matrix can share the same minimal and characteristic polynomials.

Actually, similar matrices are characterised by the so-called *similarity invariants*, based on *Frobenius decomposition*. Any endomorphism $f$ of a finite dimensional vector space $E$ over a field $K$ makes this vector space a module over the P.I.D. $K[X]$, scalar multiplication being defined by
$$X\cdot v=f(v).$$
It turns out this module is a finitely generated torsion module. As all such modules, it has *invariant factors* $\;p_1,\dots,p_r$ such that for each $i=1, \dots, r-1$, $p_i\mid p_{i+1}$.

In the case of the module associated to the pair $(E,u)$, these invariant factors are called the *similarity invariants* of the endomorphism. The last invariant is the minimal polynomial of $u$, and the product $\;p_1\dotsm p_r\;$ is its characteristic polynomial.